# @ResponseBody returns empty object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, uuid

When I use below to get the user object it works just fine.

```
@GetMapping("/findOne") 
@ResponseBody
public Optional<AppUser> findOne (Long id) {
    return appUserRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Above gives me a response back as:

```
{"id":1,"useruuid":"863db606-9af6-48a8-963a-07b9fe0fc4fc","useremail":"user1@mydomain.com"}
```

Now, I am trying to search based on UUID(4) using this:

```
@GetMapping("/findOneUsingUUID") 
@ResponseBody
public AppUser findOne (String useruuid) {
    return appUserRepository.findByUseruuid(useruuid);
}
```

This doesn't return anything. No error, no warning whatsoever. While this gives me all the details I need:

```
AppUser appUser = appUserRepository.findByUseruuid("863db606-9af6-48a8-963a-07b9fe0fc4fc");
    System.out.println(" >>>      " + appUser.getUseruuid());
    System.out.println(" >>>      " + appUser.getId());
    System.out.println(" >>>      " + appUser.getUseremail());
```

This is what I have in my Repository

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {
AppUser findByUseruuid(String useruuid);
```

and Entity

```
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "useruuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid4")
private String useruuid;
```

**Question:**
Why my controller method `@GetMapping("/findOneUsingUUID")`  is not returning anything? Any relevant info/help/link will be greatly appreciated.

**Update (for sidgate's comment/question):**
I tested this inside another controller method. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "tableusers" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {
       
        AppUser appUser = appUserRepository.findByUseruuid("863db606-9af6-48a8-963a-07b9fe0fc4fc");
        System.out.println(" >>>      " + appUser.getUseruuid());
        System.out.println(" >>>      " + appUser.getId());
        System.out.println(" >>>      " + appUser.getUseremail());
        
        String tableusers = "tableusers";
        model.addAttribute("tableusers", tableusers);

        List<AppUser> users = appUserService.findAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("metaTitle", "All Users");
        return "user_table_data_table";
        
    }
```

**Update 2:**

Now I have the following in my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findOnebyId/{uuid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public AppUser findOneByUUID2(@PathVariable final String useruuid) {
        return appUserRepository.findByUseruuid(useruuid);
    }
```

So my URL becomes similar to this:

```
http://localhost:8080/findOnebyId?id=eeadf17f-13f2-4939-bab6-2534fcc1f4d4
```

But now getting 404 error in my browser console.

**Update 3:**

Per Dale's suggestion, I fixed it and checked in code to [github-repo](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootCM). All works fine now.

Comment: could you add how  are writing the repositoty appUserRepository?

Comment: Are you saying your print statements prints the values, but controller doesn't return anything? can you share the actual code? your print statements aren't in controller function.

Comment: How are you passing id and uuid to controller methods?

Comment: As a note, your database performance will be *much* better if you can use a real UUID column (which is just a 128-bit number) instead of a string. (The last I knew, everything except MySQL supported it.)

Comment: Updated appUserRepository code Tino89.

Comment: Pirho - This is how I am calling the controller method: <a href="#" th:data-parameter1="${user.useruuid}" onclick="openUserModal(this.getAttribute('data-parameter1'));">Get Details</a>. This give me empty response. However using Id it works flawlessly. Please help. If you wish I can share the Jquery snippet for this too. FYI, this works - <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" th:onClick="'javascript:openUserModal(\''+ ${user.id} + '\');'">Details</a>

Comment: I am more interested about how you pick the values on your controller side. No `@PathVariable`, `@RequestParam`, `@RequestBody` or so for `id` or `useruuid`?

Comment: @pirho, Here is a similar example where using id it works- https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootThymeleafJQueryFragments/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/tables/usertable.html

Comment: Yes, there is `@PathVariable("id")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this out based on you GitHub code and the API worked flawlessly for me via Postman. The problem might be with the way you are invoking the API.

In the comments section you mentioned that your are passing values to controllers as path variables. But you haven't added the `@PathVariable` annotation in the controller method. So the controller method is expecting a query paramter, not a path variable. Please try invoking the API by passing UUID as parameter.

**EDIT**

Looking at your GitHub code, you are calling the API as `url: "/findOnebyId?id="+ id`.

```java
@GetMapping("/findOnebyId")
    @ResponseBody
    public AppUser findOneByUUID(String useruuid) {
        return appUserRepository.findByUseruuid(useruuid);
    }
```

In this controller method, you are expecting `useruuid` as query parameter. But in your datatables.html file, you are sending the query parameter as `id`.

So you can remove the `@PathVariable` annotation and correct the query parameter name in the AJAX request.

Comment: If you look at the code I am making that URL from javascript. That means if you click Get Details button it show the Id and Uuid. Plz help.

Comment: **http://localhost:8080/findOnebyId?id=863db606-9af6-48a8-963a-07b9fe0fc4fc** - This is the request you are sending to fetch the data. Here you are sending a query parameter named **id**. But in the controller method you are expecting a query parameter named **useruuid**. So your URL will be **http://localhost:8080/findOnebyId?useruuid=863db606-9af6-48a8-963a-07b9fe0fc4fc**

Comment: Hi Dale, added more info as "Update 2" still I am getting null.

Comment: @AjayKumar issue is not with Path Variable. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Mannn...! Such silly mistake I made. I will set my SuperHero name as "Dale" if I am going to write a comic Novel :-). Thanks for your consistent help. Keep up the good work. Every time I put a question on SO I am amazed by community response. Wondering if there would be no SO then how the code development world would have looked like :-)

Comment: Happy to help @AjayKumar

Answer (score 0):

Since you are declaring the method `findByUseruuid()` in your `AppUserRepository interface` then you also need to provide the query on which the data will be returned from db.

**For example:**

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {

@Query("select vm FROM table_name vm where vm.useruuid = :useruuid")
AppUser findByUseruuid(String useruuid);
```

where AppUser is entity class with proper annotation used.

It seems that you need to fix your controller ,You are missing `@QueryParam` or `@PathParam` at your function findOneByUUID ....need to add as mentioned below

```
 @GetMapping("/findOnebyId")
    @ResponseBody
    public AppUser findOneByUUID(@QueryParam("useruuid") String useruuid)
```

Comment: I am getting results as shown in sysout above. That is not an issue. Issue is when I call the URL for uuid, it gives me empty result.

Comment: obviously because  findByUseruuid(String useruuid) is not a build in function for JpaRepository ,so try running query on that as i sugested

Comment: Can you share AppUser class content

Comment: To not to spam this page further I added the entire project here :-) - https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootCM for your convenience here is the direct link to AppUser class - https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootCM/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/model/AppUser.java