# Spring MVC Controller not receiving atribute from Template with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a template which represents a list of notes that are retrieved from a database

```
  <tr th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(allNotes)}"
                            th:each="note : ${allNotes}">
                            <td>
                                <form action="#" method="POST" th:action="@{/home/editNote}"
                                      th:object="${note}">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="noteId" name="noteId" th:value="*{noteId}">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
                                            onclick="editNoteModal('updateNote', this.getAttribute('data-noteId'),
                                            this.getAttribute('data-noteTitle'),
                                             this.getAttribute('data-noteDescription'))">Edit
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                                <form action="#" method="POST" th:action="@{/home/deleteNote}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="noteId" th:value="*{note.noteId}">
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <th scope="row" th:text="${note.noteTitle}">Example Note Title</th>
                            <td th:text="${note.noteDescription}">Example Note Description</td>
                            </form>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

In the GUI It looks like this
[image: ExampleNote List]

This is my modal code which should open after I click on the edit button:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="editNoteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="noteModalLabel"
                     aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editnoteModalLabel">Note</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                 </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="note-title" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="noteTitle" class="form-control" id="editNoteTitle"
                                               maxlength="20" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="note-description" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="noteDescription" id="editNoteDescription"
                                                  rows="5" maxlength="1000" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <button id="editNoteSubmit" type="submit" class="d-none"></button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#editNoteModal').click();">
                                    Save
                                    changes
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In the GUI it looks like this:
[image: ModalCode]

I want to be able to edit given note and then send the edited id to the controller so I can update this change within the database. I have correct database logic for the update, I just don't know the way how to send the given notes id and changed information to my controller.

```
 @PostMapping("/editNote")
    public String editNote(@ModelAttribute(value = "note") Note note,
                           @ModelAttribute(value = "noteId") NoteIdModel noteIdModel, Model model,
                           Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("noteid " + note.getNoteId());
        System.out.println("noteidHidden " + noteIdModel.getNoteIdHidden());
        System.out.println("notedesc" + note.getNoteDescription());
        noteService.editNote(note, authentication);
        return "result";
    }
```

However, the incoming noteId is null. I have checked the database and the note with correct id is indeed in the database and is also retrieved from the database. It's just not sent to the controller.

Comment: It seems depends on javascript function `editNoteModal`, executes `POST`.(Thymeleaf does not submit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

#### HTML fragment

```
<tr th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(allNotes)}"
    th:each="note : ${allNotes}">
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
            th:data-noteId="${note.noteId}"
            th:data-noteTitle="${note.noteTitle}"
            th:data-noteDescription="${note.noteDescription}"
            onclick="editNoteModal('updateNote', this.getAttribute('data-noteId'),this.getAttribute('data-noteTitle'),this.getAttribute('data-noteDescription'))">Edit
        </button><br/>
        <a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
    </td>
    <td scope="row" th:text="${note.noteTitle}"></td>
    <td th:text="${note.noteDescription}"></td>
</tr>
```

#### JS fragment

```
/**
* Fill edit modal with current information
*/
function editNoteModal(modal, noteId, noteTitle, noteDescription) {
    $('#editnoteModalLabel').text("Note " + noteId);
    $('#editNoteId').val(noteId);
    $('#editNoteTitle').val(noteTitle);
    $('#editNoteDescription').val(noteDescription);
    
    $('#editNoteModal').modal("show");
}

/**
* Save to backend edit information
*/
function save() {
    var noteId = $('#editNoteId').val();
    var noteTitle = $('#editNoteTitle').val();
    var noteDescription = $('#editNoteDescription').val();
     $.ajax({
        url : "./editNote",
        method : "POST",
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        data : JSON.stringify({
            noteId : noteId,
            noteTitle : noteTitle,
            noteDescription : noteDescription
        }),
        success : function(result) {
            $('#editNoteModal').modal("hide");
            alert(result);
        }
    }) 
}
```

#### Backend

```
@PostMapping(path = "/editNote", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> editNote(@RequestBody Note note) {
    System.out.println("noteid " + note.getNoteId());
    System.out.println("noteidTitle " + note.getNoteTitle());
    System.out.println("notedesc" + note.getNoteDescription());
    
    //Save in database
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
}
```

Comment: And how should I retrieve those values from hidden input fields on the side of the controller please ?

Comment: @Patrick check my update please, maybe that's what are you looking for

Comment: Did you mean the second button to be also edit ? There are two edit buttons in your code. Once I have the list of notes, each and every one of them has a button called edit which opens up the modal and then button save which sends saved changed user types in that particular modal.

Comment: @Patrick each button saves individual note. I don't know your full code. I've replicated based on your sample code. You need to post more complete code or paste what is your error to replicate

Comment: @Patrick Updated. This code will update notes individually with Ajax call. Once updated, you need to ensure to rerender your table with updated notes

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did while I was [trying to pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688472/responsebody-returns-empty-object) the id to open a modal by finding details using that id:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                th:data-parameter1="${user.useruuid}"
                onclick="openUserModal(this.getAttribute('data-parameter1'));">Details</a>
```

And then somewhere in your JavaScript, you can something (similar) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:fragment="includeModalScript">
function openUserModal(id) {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/findOnebyId?id="+ id,
        success: function(data){
            alert(id);
            .......
</script>
```

And my controller looked like this:

```
@GetMapping("/findOnebyId")
@ResponseBody
public AppUser findOneByUUID(String id) {
....    
}
```

You can take a look [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootCM/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/fragments/tables/usertable.html), [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootCM/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/fragments/js/datatables.html) and [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootCM) for a working demo similar to your issue/requirement.